# How to map one input field to multiple columns in Spring Boots @Column

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

There is one search input field that can takes either policyid or docid. So, what I wondering, how can I map this input field to two different column in database using @Column

```
 @Column(name = "policyid")
  @Getter
  @Setter
  protected String policyId;

@Column(name = "docid")
  @Getter
  @Setter
  protected String docId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use like query i.e select * from tableName where policyid like '%irt%' or docid like '%irt%'.

You can't map same 2 field for same column or  vice versa